# how can we perform element wise Logical OR operation ?

Tags: matlab, binary, logical-or

how can we perform element wise Logical OR operation on two vectors of different size having binary values?

Comment: How do you define an element-wise operation on two vectors of different size? Element-wise operations are only defined for vectors of equal size.

Comment: actually sir i have decimal values, so when i convert them to binary, some times there size differs. Example - 3 is 11 in binary and 5 is 101 in binary and i want its output as 111 i.e. 7 but there size are not same, so i am not getting that.

Comment: I want output as 1+1=1, 1+0=1, 0+1=1 and 0+0=0. here 1 and 0 are binary and i use '+' for OR operation

Comment: Give an example "Logical OR operation on 'two vectors of different size' "

Comment: Thank u all. I got my answer .. Using function de2bi(3,4,'left-msb') I get the size as i wanted. In this 3 is my decimal number, 4 is the size and 'left-msb' is used for left padding.  So by using this I get decimal 3 in binary as 0 0 1 1 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using functions from core MATLAB only (namely [`dec2bin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dec2bin.html) and [`bin2dec`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bin2dec.html)):

```
a = 3;
b = 5;

bits = dec2bin(a,8)-'0' | dec2bin(b,8)-'0';
c = bin2dec(char(bits+'0'));
```

where `c` will be `7` as expected